# Angular 6 - update deep object inside array

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a config object to send from X component to Y component

from the Y component i filter the columns to get only the unique monoselect, then for each column i want to update the options of monoselectConfig.

the problem is that i can update the options but when i display the config object i don't find the modifications i just made

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-srhkvl)

```
  config = {
    value: this.result,
    columns: [
      {
        field: "speciality",
        type: "monoselect",
        monoselectConfig: { options: this.options },
        unique: true
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I hope the below answer resolved your issue, if so please upvote as well so that it could be useful to others also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were doing the filtering correctly but you were not updating the object properly.

I have reviewed your code in the stackblitz, you just need minor changes in your ngOnChanges() method.

So just update your ngOnChanges() method by the below code. This would update your **configurations** object as well.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes["config"] && changes["config"].currentValue) {

      this.configuration = changes["config"].currentValue;

      // get all unique monoselect
      let monoselectsUnique = this.configuration.columns.filter(element => element.type === "monoselect" && element.unique == true);
      console.log(monoselectsUnique)
      if (monoselectsUnique.length > 0) {
        monoselectsUnique.forEach(element => {

          // get all options not exist in the array result
          let newOption = element.monoselectConfig.options.filter(item => !this.config.value.map(item => item[element.field].code).includes(item.code));

          // update the config object with the new option
          // monoselectsUnique = { ...monoselectsUnique.monoselectConfig, options: newOption }
          element.monoselectConfig.options= newOption
        })
         console.log(monoselectsUnique)
        console.log(this.configuration)
      }

    }
  }
```